# Cannot Start service AppfabricCachingService

Tags: appfabric, appfabric-cache

I have a newly created cluster with XML as a connection string.
The XML was placed in a share with a "EVERYONE" read\write permission.
I'm unable to start the cluster for some reason.

[image]

Both nodes services are configured to run under the local network service.
When trying to run them manually I get a "access denied".
After trying to run them under an admin account they do run I get the following:

[image]

This is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="dataCache" type="Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheSection, Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Core" />
  </configSections>
  <dataCache size="Small">
    <caches>
      <cache consistency="StrongConsistency" name="default" minSecondaries="0">
        <policy>
          <eviction type="Lru" />
          <expiration defaultTTL="10" isExpirable="true" />
        </policy>
      </cache>
    </caches>
    <hosts>
      <host replicationPort="22236" arbitrationPort="22235" clusterPort="22234"
        hostId="1482085959" size="2047" leadHost="true" account="NAYAXVEND\QAILCACHE02$"
        cacheHostName="AppFabricCachingService" name="QAILCACHE02.nayaxvend.int"
        cachePort="22233" />
      <host replicationPort="22236" arbitrationPort="22235" clusterPort="22234"
        hostId="1105037502" size="2047" leadHost="true" account="NAYAXVEND\QAILCACHE03$"
        cacheHostName="AppFabricCachingService" name="QAILCACHE03.nayaxvend.int"
        cachePort="22233" />
    </hosts>
    <deploymentSettings>
      <deploymentMode value="RoutingClient" />
    </deploymentSettings>
  </dataCache>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much pain,
it turns out you need to use a Domain Username and NOT the Local Network User per Microsoft's recommendation.
Just start the setup normally and you should be good to go.